# Django 1.11 TypeError context must be a dict rather than Context

Tags: python, django, django-views

Just received the Sentry error `TypeError context must be a dict rather than Context.` on one of my forms.  I know it has something to do with Django 1.11, but I am not sure what to change to fix it.

**Offending line**

`message = get_template('email_forms/direct_donation_form_email.html').render(Context(ctx))`

**Entire View**

```
def donation_application(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DirectDonationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
            name = request.POST.get('name', '')
            address = request.POST.get('address', '')
            city = request.POST.get('city', '')
            state = request.POST.get('state', '')
            zip = request.POST.get('zip', '')
            phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number', '')
            support = request.POST.get('support', '')
            agree = request.POST.get('agree', '')
            email_address = request.POST.get('email_address', '')
            number = request.POST.get('number', '')
            cvc = request.POST.get('cvc', '')
            exp = request.POST.get('exp', '')
            # token = form.cleaned_data['stripe_token'],
            # exp_m = int(request.POST.get('exp_month', ''))
            # exp_y = int(request.POST.get('exp_year', ''))

            exp_month = exp[0:2]
            exp_year = exp[5:9]

            subject = 'New Donation'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            recipient_list = ['deniselarkins@/////\\\\\.com',
                              'charles@/////\\\\\.net',
                              'marcmunic@/////\\\\\.com',
                              ]

            token = stripe.Token.create(
                card={
                    'number': number,
                    'exp_month': exp_month,
                    'exp_year': exp_year,
                    'cvc': cvc
                },
            )

            customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                email=email_address,
                source=token,
            )

            total_support = decimal.Decimal(support) / 100
            total_charge = decimal.Decimal(int(support)) / 100

            # Charge the user's card:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=total_charge,
                currency='usd',
                description='Donation',
                customer=customer.id
            )

            ctx = {
                'name': name,
                'address': address,
                'city': city,
                'state': state,
                'zip': zip,
                'phone_number': phone_number,
                'email_address': email_address,
                'agree': agree,
                'charge': charge,
                'customer': customer,
                'total_support': total_support,
                'total_charge': total_charge
            }

            message = get_template('email_forms/direct_donation_form_email.html').render(Context(ctx))
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email=from_email, to=recipient_list)
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            msg.send(fail_silently=True)

            return redirect(
                '/contribute/donation-support-thank-you/?name=' + name +
                '&address=' + address +
                '&state=' + state +
                '&city=' + city +
                '&zip=' + zip +
                '&phone_number=' + phone_number +
                '&email_address=' + email_address +
                '&total_support=' + str(total_support) +
                '&total_charge=' + str(total_charge)
            )
    context = {
        'title': 'Donation Pledge',
    }

    return render(request, 'contribute/_donation-application.html', context)
```

Comment: [*If context is provided, it must be a dict.*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In [Django 1.8+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.8/#dictionary-and-context-instance-arguments-of-rendering-functions), the template's `render` method takes a dictionary for the `context` parameter. Support for passing a `Context` instance [is deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10), and gives an error in Django 1.10+.

In your case, just use a regular `dict` instead of a `Context` instance:

```
message = get_template('email_forms/direct_donation_form_email.html').render(ctx)
```

You may prefer to use the [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) shortcut:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

message = render_to_string('email_forms/direct_donation_form_email.html', ctx)
```

If you were using `RequestContext` instead of `Context`, then you would pass the `request` to these methods as well so that the context processors run.

```
message = get_template('email_forms/direct_donation_form_email.html').render(ctx, request=request)
message = render_to_string('email_forms/direct_donation_form_email.html', ctx, request=request)
```

Comment: is this only for when you are loading in templates?  It's curious to me because in the shell I created a test template then tried to just pass a dict but it was complaining that it wasn't a context, which seems odd to me that it would be one way for one but not the same way for the other

Comment: @DavidTorrey if your manually construct a `django.template.Template` then you still have to pass a `Context` instance. It's a bit confusing that the API is different depending on whether you do `template = Template(...)` or `template = get _template(...)`.

Comment: @AnonymousUser this question is about upgrading to Django 1.11. Async views didn’t come until much later so your comment seems off topic

Answer (score 19):

Migrated from Django 1.8 to Django 1.11.6

Wherever i had a RequestContext class, there is a method flatten() wich return the result as a dict.

So if the class is RequestContext....

```
return t.render(context)
```

becomes

```
return t.render(context.flatten())
```

And in a case wich the context is is wrapped by Context(), just remove it. Because Context() is deprecated.

```
return t.render(Context(ctx))
```

becomes

```
return t.render(ctx)
```

Comment: Instead of flattening a `RequestContext`, it might be possible to use a dictionary and pass the request as well, e.g. `t.render(ctx, request=request)`.

Comment: I get **name 't' is not defined**. What should `t` be?

Answer (score 2):

For django 1.11 and after, context must be dict.

You can use:

```
context_dict = get_context_dict(context)
return t.render(context_dict)
```

or

```
context_dict = context.flatten()
return t.render(context_dict)
```

Comment: The function `get_context_dict` doesn't appear to exist in Django.

Answer (score 0):

I got here because I had the same issue. I'm learning Django with [Django Unleashed](https://://django-unleashed.com/) by Andrew Pinkham. It's a book from 2015.

I found in the official documentation, that a dictionary must be passed to the context parameter and not a Context instance (from django.template.Context).

@Alasdair suggested to use render_to_string, but, at least in Django 3.2 the
render method use render_to_string method intrinsically.

```
def render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None):
"""
Return a HttpResponse whose content is filled with the result of calling
django.template.loader.render_to_string() with the passed arguments.
"""
content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
return HttpResponse(content, content_type, status)
```

so, using just the render method could be better. I provide this answer because was the one that I was looking for and it may help some one reaching this Stack Overflow question.