# graphite-web and ubuntu 18.04

Tags: graphite

I am trying to set up graphite-web on a freshly installed ubuntu 18.04 system. I used the apt packet manager, so I got the 1.0.2 version of graphite-web. I finished the configuration als usual, however I got an "Internal Server Error" when trying to open graphite-web in the browser. The apache error log of graphite web says:

```
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.097839 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX] mod_wsgi (pid=13350): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi'.
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.102111 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.102210 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157, in __call__
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.102389 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.102535 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.102706 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     response = self._middleware_chain(request)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.102964 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.103063 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.103144 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.103263 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.103502 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 143, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.103660 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     return callback(request, **param_dict)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.103737 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/views.py", line 11, in server_error
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.103889 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     return HttpResponseServerError( template.render(context) )
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.104044 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 64, in render
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.104484 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.104582 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 287, in make_context
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.104868 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.105070 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13350] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX] TypeError: context must be a dict rather than Context.
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.435785 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX] mod_wsgi (pid=13387): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi'.
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.436040 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.436131 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157, in __call__
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.436272 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.436386 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.436646 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     response = self._middleware_chain(request)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.436744 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.436876 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.437023 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.437173 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.437321 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 143, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.437570 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     return callback(request, **param_dict)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.437755 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/views.py", line 11, in server_error
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.437960 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     return HttpResponseServerError( template.render(context) )
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.438139 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 64, in render
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.438273 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.438392 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 287, in make_context
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.438609 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX]     raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
[Fri May 25 07:02:47.438816 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13387] [remote XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX] TypeError: context must be a dict rather than Context.
```

At first I thought that the dirctory that contains the wsgi script was not owned by the right user, but it turned out that this was not the case. (It is owned by the web-servers user)

Currently I am using python 2.7 but I was able to replicate the problem using python3.

I am running out of ideas. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I managed to fix this problem inside usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/views.py

by changing

```
  context = Contex({
    'stacktrace' : traceback.format_exc()
  })
```

to

```
  context = {
    'stacktrace' : traceback.format_exc()
  }
```

The problem was related to this topic:
[Django 1.11 TypeError context must be a dict rather than Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787700/django-1-11-typeerror-context-must-be-a-dict-rather-than-context)

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  Hopefully this gets addressed somewhere.