# How do I output from views.py to html template

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my code:

```
class Predict(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        employeeId = 44
        return render(request, 'InventoryShop/home.html', {'employeeId': employeeId})
```

What I want to achieve is to output this `employeeId` on the `home.html`, from this scope.
But this code gives an error when trying to run it:

```
context must be a dict rather than set.
```

When I put this `employeeId` outside the scope, I am able to output it without problem though:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'employeeId' : employeeId
    }
    return render(request, 'InventoryShop/home.html', context)
```

Edit: I'm aware of the changes from 1.8 to 1.11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.11 TypeError context must be a dict rather than Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787700/django-1-11-typeerror-context-must-be-a-dict-rather-than-context)

Comment: This code wouldn't give that error. You'd get it if you did `{'employeeId', employeeId}`, ie with a comma rather than a colon.