# Why am i getting the TypeError:context must be a dict rather than Context. Django

Tags: python, django

Trying to setup a webpage to list the tags for startups (following along in Django unleashed). The book uses Django 1.8, and Im using 3.0. There are spots where ive seen deprecated functions in the book and was able to find what the updated replacement was, but i cant figure out why django is giving me this error when loading the homepage. Still kinda new at Python and Django. I do have tags created, when executing `Tag.objects.all()` and one startup has been saved to the database which has its related tag.

### Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from .models import Tag 
from django.template import Template, Context, loader

def homepage(request):
    tag_list = Tag.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('organizer/tag_list.html')
    context = Context({'tag_list':tag_list})
    output   = template.render(context)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

### Tag_list.html

```
{% extends parent_template|default:"organizer/base_organizer.html" %} #An alternative reference to "base.html"

{% block title %}
{{ block.super }} - Tag List 
{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
<h2>Tag List</h2>
<ul>
    {% for tag in tag_list %}
      <li>
        <a href="">
          {{ tag.name|title }}</a>
      </li>

    {% empty %}
  <p><em>There are currently no Tags available.</em></p>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

TypeError at /

```
context must be a dict rather than Context.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.0
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

context must be a dict rather than Context.

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Antho\Desktop\suorganizer\su_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py in make_context, line 270
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Antho\Desktop\suorganizer\su_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.5
Python Path:
```

Comment: In django 1.8+ Context instance are no longer in use, instead you will pass context as a dictionary https://stackoverflow.com/a/43787762/11225821 . I recommend you to read over django docs instead of books that use old version of django that no longer in uses https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass context variables as **dict** objects to the template as below,

```
def homepage(request):
    tag_list = Tag.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('organizer/tag_list.html')
    context = {'tag_list': tag_list} # update this line
    output = template.render(context)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Also, you could rewrite the view by using [**`render()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function

```
def homepage(request):
    tag_list = Tag.objects.all()
    context = {'tag_list': tag_list}
    return render(request, 'organizer/tag_list.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks! After sorting out errors then with folder location it worked!!!