# Showing a generated document using django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, python-requests

I have a Django site and want it so that when the user presses a button on the site that a python file makes a word document and shows it to the user in the browser.
I am getting an error saying that `context must be a dict rather than set.`
my document seems to be made in my pycharm project folder but it doesn't want to show itself for some reason.

my process is as follows: user clicks a html button. `urls.py` then points the browser to a function in my `view.py` called `making_the_doc`. This `making_the_doc` function runs a function in my `the plot.py` file which will generate the document and returns it to `view.py` for presentation to the user.

Firstly i created the code that will generate the document. This file is known as `theplot.py`.

THEPLOT.PY

```
def making_a_doc_function(request):

doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_heading('hello')
doc.save('this is doc.docx')
generated_doc = open('this is doc.docx', 'rb')
response = FileResponse(generated_doc)

return render(request, 'doc.html', {response})
```

Then I linked this function to my `views.py`

VIEWS.PY

```
def making_the_doc(request):

return making_a_doc_function(request)
```

Then i created my url paths to point to the `views.py`

URLS.PY

```
path('making_a_doc', views.making_the_doc, name='doc'),
```

finally I generate my `html` button so the whole process can start off when the button is clicked:

INDEX.HTML

```
<input type="button" value="generating" onclick="window.open('making_a_doc')">
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 1.11 TypeError context must be a dict rather than Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787700/django-1-11-typeerror-context-must-be-a-dict-rather-than-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a dict to your render function. A change like this should make it work

def making_a_doc_function(request):

```
  doc = docx.Document()
  doc.add_heading('hello')
  doc.save('this is doc.docx')
  generated_doc = open('this is doc.docx', 'rb')
  response = {"generated_doc": FileResponse(generated_doc)}

  return render(request, 'doc.html', response)
```

Comment: this gives me an error saying `unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: I edited the answer. The {} in the last line have been removed

Comment: Great thank you it opens up a window with no errors so im presuming that this is correct now. however nothing is shown in the window. Is this because it is opening i have nothing in my `doc.html` file. i presumed it would open the file itself?